# aframe-react: TypeError: setting getter-only property "document" aframe-master.js:62727

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, aframe

I have a project using React, ReactRouter Bootstrap, THREEJS, Apollo, react-proxy-loader and webpack.
I want to replace manually written THREEJS code with aframe. I added the following simple component:

```
import 'aframe';
import 'react';

function AFrame (){
return (
  <a-scene>
  <a-entity position="0 .7 0">
    <a-entity id="camera" camera look-controls wasd-controls universal-controls></a-entity>
  </a-entity>
  <a-box
    position="-.5 .1 -1"
    rotation="0 0 0"
    width=".2" height=".2" depth=".2"
    color="#33cc33">
    </a-box>
  </a-scene>
);
}

export default AFrame;
```

Adding it as as a route gives me the error on the title.
Looking into aframe-master.js I find this:

```
(function (global){
// This is the entry point if requiring/importing via       node, or 
// a build tool that uses package.json entry (like browserify, webpack).          
// If running in node with a window mock available, globalize its members
// if needed. Otherwise, just continue to./main
if (typeof global !== 'undefined' && global.window) { 
 global.document = global.window.document; 
 global.navigator =  global.window.navigator; 
}
```

So I assume, global.document can not be accessed. I tried commenting out everything THREEJS related, apollo provider and the proxy stuff - still no luck.

I added the same component to an example using react-scripts where it worked perfectly.

Has anyone got an idea where this error is caused? Could it be a webpack issue?

Does anyone have any idea where this comes from?

Comment: Sorry, really hard to tell. Too many dependencies!

Comment: I thought it might be a known error from other configurations that could point me to a clue...Thank you for answering :)

Comment: In the end I solved it using webpack externals
webpack.config:
  `externals: {
  "aframe" : "AFRAME"
    }`